# Как в шаблоне html значение True поменять на ВЫПОЛНЕНО? Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

Ну вся проблема указана в заголовке вопроса. Можно скинуть ссылкой на более развернутый ответ( к примеру документация). Возможно это все надо делать через js

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под `шаблон html`?. работу с тегом [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)?

Comment: Средствами шаблонизатора - через `{% if var1 %}Выполнено{% else %}Не выполнено{% endif %}`. Ссылку могу дать на официальную документацию Django, но я думаю вы и сами ее найдете.

Comment: `value|yesno:"Выполнено,Не выполнено"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

фильтр yesno. Пример использования `{{ value|yesno:"выполнено,нет,ничего" }}` `value` - это значение. выполнено - `True`, нет - `False`, ничего - `None`